# Regression sensitivity analysis by re-sampling duplicates

Tags: r, regression, bootstrap, resampling, sensitivity-analysis

In R, I have completed a simple regression of the form lm(Y~x+a). The dataset original dataset included several non-independent data points, which I selected among using a set of rules. I want to test the robustness of the regression results by randomly resampling one from each set of the "duplicate" (non-independent) data points and completing something like a bootstrap. As an example, a subset of the data look like this:

```
Index x       a      Y
1   0.33    61.04   0.95
2   0.41    8.67    1.16
3   0.00    6.19    0.91
4   0.00    13.60   0.95
5   0.10    3.72    0.94
6   0.00    5.14    1.04
7   0.00    23.16   0.00
8   0.03    7.59    0.98
9   0.00    14.44   1.12
10  0.10    11.17   1.06
10  0.18    10.64   1.12
10  0.05    10.82   1.10
10  0.10    10.13   0.00
10  0.00    11.61   1.02
10  0.00    11.61   1.03
10  0.18    8.53    0.00
10  0.00    11.61   1.11
10  0.18    10.64   1.06
```

I would like to randomly include one of the Index = 10 records each time the regression is run, then calculate confidence intervals for the regression intercept and slopes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a newer method. But what do you accomplish by doing it? What exactly is your question?

My suggestion is to not use biased/stratified sampling (or sample subsets of dependent records), but rather account for the dependence using mixed models/multilevel models or clustered errors.

You can find several texts for mixed models and some SO discussions on regression with clustered errors.

In your approach, you may loose information while sampling from groups.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use a mixed-model approach because only a small number of the Index values have duplicates. My understanding is that it is incorrect to calculate random effects when there are very few replicates of many levels of the random term.
What I want to know is whether the regression parameters (intercept and slopes) are robust to the choice of duplicate (for the few levels of Index where there are duplicates)